# ArrayAdapter not accepting RelativeLayout as its row resource

Tags: android, android-listview, android-relativelayout, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to create a `ListView` using the following code:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.settings_items, settingsLabels));
```

With `settingsLabels` being a string array and `settings_items` being a `RelativeLayout`, including both a `TextView` and an `ImageView`. Unfortunately, I cannot parse this as the resource. How do I properly implement this? The `ImageView` source is the same regardless of item. What is the easiest way to get around this ?

**EDIT settings_item.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settings_item_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_leftarrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot parse this as the resource"?

Comment: show us R.layout.settings_items layout xml ...

Comment: 02-23 11:44:14.843: E/AndroidRuntime(21928): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

Comment: then pick up one of the answers and change R.id.id_of_textView to R.id.settings_item_label and should be fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code for creating the adapter like this:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.settings_items, R.id.id_of_textView, settingsLabels));
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 3):

Use this constructor:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.settings_items, R.id.id_of_textView, settingsLabels));
```

The constructor you used requires that the layout supplied is a `TextView`. Here is a link from the docs about the constructors: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int,%20java.util.List%3CT%3E%29